# What must be the minimum upload data rate to get datas from Google Analytics for Android?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I use google analytics tool to get user data from my Android App. I know this is a very specific question but simply "What must be minimum upload data rate to get datas from Google Analytics for Android?"

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "minimum upload data rate to get datas"?  If you are asking what the minimum amount of stats are to start seeing data then it's basically "1".  But you need to note that google analytics will not show you any stats until the next day.  You can sometimes see some basic stats in the "realtime" info but it's not always accurate.

Comment: No i mean, data rate as kbps while using mobile data to connect internet. when i use EDGE speed there is no action in realtime info, so i want to know the minimum data rate.

Comment: I see. I don't think there will be any info on that.  Analytics should be sending very little data though and I would suspect it should be able to work on EDGE.  Make sure that it's not failing due to the connection type changing as you open your app.  e.g. close app, change connection to EDGE, wait 2-3 min, open app.  It's also possible that it will show up tomorrow in the stats.  I've had apps before where it only shows on realtime 1/3 times but all stats are there the next day.

Comment: I ve waited for 10 minutes and more but seen nothing in realtime. You may be right about general overview. Thanks.

Comment: i checked my app overview page but didn't get any infos while using EDGE.

Comment: It is realtime data. Could it be that no one is on your site at the time you are checking?

Comment: I dont have a web site integrated Google Analytics, i use android application. At least 1 person (me) is using app while i am checking it. EDGE speed is not fast enough to send datas, i think and wonder the minimum speed.